# MapFragment Showing null which leads to googleMaps to be null

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

In MainActivity.java

```
try
{
  supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
  initializeMap();
}catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) method in MainActivity.java

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    Context context = this;

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location currentLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    latitudeCurr = currentLocation.getLatitude();
    longitudeCurr = currentLocation.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "lat "+latitudeCurr+"    long "+longitudeCurr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return  ;
    }
```

But mapFragment is getting null. I also tried using

```
 mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using this:

```
SupportMapFragment m = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
m.getMapAsync(this);
```

inside Fragment.java as we are here calling the child Fragment of that same Fragment, and it solved the issue.